# How to run the file-copy dialog of thunar, or anything similar to use?

Tags: files, xfce, thunar

I'm trying to create a Send To menu for thunar, which copies a file (%F) to a fixed location.

In KDE4 I could use `kioclient copy` command, but what about other environment? Does thunar has something similar or is there any other file copy dialog I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an utility such as [checkcopy](http://de.mcbf.net/david/checkcopy/) or even plain `cp` (beware, though, of the 'overwrite by default' issues). To my knowledge, and I'm using development version of `Xfce`, `Thunar` doesn't expose its copy functionality to the user.

This guide explains how to [customize the "Send To" Menu](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/send-to) in `Thunar`. Alternatively, and perhaps more straightforward, this guide explains how to [define custom actions](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) via `Edit > Configure custom actions...`.